# Force a certain version of git on push to remote repo

Tags: git

I'm not sure if this is something that is kind of bonkers, but I know certain repo's (such as Atlassian Stash) allow you to setup remote git hooks.  We have various developers who are using a very old version of git and I was wondering if there is some way on a push to have the repo report back to them "You should upgrade from git 1.7 to something more modern".

I know locally you can setup githooks but I'm under the impression there is no way to automatically "seed" a repo with hooks - its up to the user to install them.

**What I'm looking for is a methodology to inform a user upon a push or a clone that they should upgrade their git version.**

We are currently using Atlassian Stash as our repo but I also have access to GitLab as well.

-- Additional Notes:

The default installed version of git is something like 1.7.  I don't recall the exact situation but there is a bug we've had 3 people run into which is corrected by using a newer version of git.  The IT folks won't upgrade the default version so I was looking for a work around

Comment: Are you anticipating specific problems if the developers continue to use older versions of Git?

Comment: Our default version is 1.7 and there is some bug people run into on occasion because they haven't pointed to a newer version of GIT.  Our IT folks WONT update the default version so I'm looking for a workaround

Comment: You have root access to your git server?

Comment: Do your developers auth with HTTP or SSH?

Comment: They use a combo - and I do have access to our stash instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not currently possible.

Git v1.7.12.1 and newer [can report their version to the other side](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/Documentation/technical/protocol-capabilities.txt?id=af608260f6e0970a59b66cc819d35b8faa15ce13#n127) ([commit](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/commit/?id=ff5effdf455bd6e694ff0bb3e0793515a2214adb)), but this version information is not made available to any hooks.  The only way to get at this information is to modify the `git-receive-pack` executable running on the server, or to write a wrapper around `git-receive-pack` that does some protocol parsing to extract the version information and do something with it.

I encourage you to send an email to the [Git mailing list](http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#git) and ask the developers to make the client's version available in a hook environment variable (if provided by the client).